# Application crashes when using CachedNetworkImage

Tags: flutter, dart

Application crashes when using CachedNetworkImage in listview. If there are a lot of pictures, then the application freezes and crashes. Is it possible to load each image one by one, asynchronously? Can I have a code example? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Can you please share what you have tried? Any code snippet ?

Comment: How many items load into your list at a time?

Comment: @ZakariaHossain The whole list. How to limit it?

Comment: If your list is big like you have a list of 500 images and try to divide this list by number of page (like divide by 30) and get the paginated data.

Comment: @ZakariaHossain No, this issue can happen with only 15 or so images as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And so, if you have the same problem as me, and you have a large list of pictures, then you can do the following:

1.Enable `ListView` pagination. So that when scrolling, not the entire `ListView` is loaded, but for example only 10 items from the `List`.

2.Compress pictures to the desired size using the following parameters:
`memCacheWidth`, `memCacheHeight`, `maxHeightDiskCache`, `maxWidthDiskCache`

Here is my example:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    memCacheWidth: 45,
    memCacheHeight: 60,
    maxHeightDiskCache: 60,
    maxWidthDiskCache: 45,
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
    imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => imageBuilderWidget(imageProvider),
    placeholder: (context, url) => placeholderWidget(),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => errorWidget(),
  );
```

After adding these options, **remove app from the emulator** and do a `flutter clean`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Image.network, it solved my crash issue on IOS.

```
Image.network('https://example.com/image.jpg',
                      errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                        print(error); //do something
                      },
      loadingBuilder: (context, Widget child,
                          ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
                        if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                                ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                                    loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
                                : null,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

if need to cache images Use [Opt imised cached image](https://pub.dev/packages/optimized_cached_image) package. I had the same issue this package solved. if not working change width of images, add pagination if possible

Answer (score 0):

After going through different solutions, this is the solution that fixed my problem. Add `debugInvertOversizedImages = true` in the app's build function. After that run the app. The log will show you something similar to the following

[image: showingOversizedImageExample]

What this basically is saying is that your widget has a limit of such and such dimension but you are using a picture that is bigger than that which is consuming such storage. Using that info you can add `memCacheHeight` and `memCacheWidth` in your `CachedNetworkImage` image similar to the following

```
CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: widget.item.leadImageUrl,
                memCacheHeight: 857,
                memCacheWidth: 568,
              )
```

This should reduce the memory usage. It has almost reduces the memory usage by 75% in my case.