# Flutter Image.network() keeps crashing in AnimatedList if there is no Internet connection

Tags: flutter, flutter-image, flutter-network

In my Flutter app, I use a `Image.network()` widget as follows to display an image:

```
Image.network(
  url,
  errorBuilder: (context, error, stacktrace) => Container(color: Colors.red),
  width: 80,
  height: 80,
  cacheWidth: 80,
  cacheHeight: 80,
)
```

That widget is part of an item used in a AnimatedList.

If I'm scrolling down my list and I don't have an Internet connection, sometimes my app crashes telling me that it can't reach `url`, even though I use errorBuilder:

```
The following SocketException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed host lookup: 'i.discogs.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)
```

So I tried another approach with the [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  placeholder: (context, url) => Container(color: Colors.red),
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(color: Colors.red),
  imageUrl: url,
  memCacheWidth: 80,
  memCacheHeight: 80,
)
```

But again, I get a similar error:

```
The following _ClientSocketException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed host lookup: 'i.discogs.com'
```

How can I fix that?

**EDIT**:

- I created a sample project [here](https://github.com/mregnauld/flutter-image-network-crash-demo), where you can easily see the problem
- I reported a bug [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/129106).
- I also reported a bug [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/851) for `cached_network_image`

Comment: I tried to use Image.network items inside AnimatedList with fake urls and also disconnected network. The app is not crashing, though it's throwing errors but errorBuilder is able to tackle it and stacktrace is still showing it. Are sure the app is crashing because of this? Can you have a thorough look at the logs. It may be possible that there may be other reason or this error is the cause of triggering some other error, making it to crash?

Comment: I look at the logs and the error was related to the Image.network(). That being said, you're right, I'll try in a separate project in order to make sure it comes from that.

Comment: I just updated my post. The workaround I found before is actually not good enough.

Comment: i tried your github code. It's working very fine. Can you try upgrading your flutter? (flutter itself not the dependencies.)

Comment: Yeah it crashes without network. Will look into it.

Comment: could you try in real device, to confirm that it's not an emulator issue or debug mode issue?

Comment: Tested, it is also there on real device.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71457972/application-crashes-when-using-cachednetworkimage . He is using placeholder property of CachedNetworkImage. I think placeholder propery may help preventing crash?

Comment: I've already updated to the latest version of Flutter, and I tested it on a real Android device. I'll try your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: I've also already tried the CachedNetworkImage solution, but I still experience the same issue, even though I use memCacheWidth/Height and maxWidth/HeightDiskCache...

Comment: I also just tried the Optimized Cached Image package and again, same problem.

Comment: Did you try Enable ListView pagination.? It may prevent loading all the items at once and will load efficiently when needed.

Comment: Yes, I implemented lazy loading in my real app (50 items max per page). But even with that, I still experience the problem.

Comment: I will think of some sort of workaround, will be back. If I can't do it, will let you know here in the comments.

Comment: Thank you! That being said, I tried again with CachedNetworkImage, but this time, I ignore every error of runtimeType "_ClientSocketException". It works much better, no error at all (even though it's not the cleanest solution), but now if I reconnect the device to the Internet, only some images are downloaded...

Comment: I also tried the same approach with Image.network() and again, only some images are downloaded, even after scrolling multiple times.

Comment: I think I have found the solution and cause. Will post the solution. Just testing it.

Comment: I have posted the solution. Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I have tested your [sample code](https://github.com/mregnauld/flutter-image-network-crash-demo).
The root cause of the error is this code in your main function, which pushes a page on top of your page if error occurs.

```
 FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
      FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);
      log(details.toString());
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        Navigator.push(
          _navigatorKey.currentState!.context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ErrorPage(error: details.toString())),
        );
      });
    };
```

Solution

```
 FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
      FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);
      log(details.toString());
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        print("test is it called?");
        // Don't push this widget to stack
        // Navigator.push(
        //   _navigatorKey.currentState!.context,
        //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ErrorPage(error: details.toString())),
        // );
      });
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I already tried that and sure, if I don't use it, I don't have any problem. The thing is: I want to keep it in my real app in order to catch unexpected errors and to display a relevant error message to the user. The workaround I found so far is to test the error type. Also, when I reconnect to the internet, even if I scroll multiple times, many image won't download until I reload the page or the app.

Comment: But by using that widget, we are forcing flutter to the show the ErrorPage, what we are thinking of crash, is that it's not a crash but an ErrorPage which we want to display on the UI. You can try back click to test after that ErrorPage is shown, which we think as a crash.

Comment: Yeah. I believe the real problem is on Flutter side: why do I have (sometimes!) a error that is thrown if it can't reach an url, even though I use `errorBuilder`? But anyway, I'll go with that solution for the moment. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You can modify Text(error) in error.dart replacing with something else, because it's showing the stacktrace in the ui, making us think of it as a crash instead.